# Powershell forms full window glass transparency

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

I'm trying to make a powershell windows form all transparent as i was able to get the aero style controls working and hiding the powershell console window this is the only thing missing.
The tutorial I was trying to implement in powershell is this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx but its in C#, help?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the C# sample itself, by compiling/loading it in PowerShell. Sample (untested):

```
$def = @"
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MARGINS
    {
       public int left; 
       public int right; 
       public int top; 
       public int bottom; 
    }

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    public static extern void DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hwnd, ref MARGINS margins);
"@

#Load/Compile C# P/Invoke code
Add-Type -Namespace stackoverflow -Name Aero -MemberDefinition $def

#Check if Aero is enabled on this computer
If([stackoverflow.Aero]::DwmIsCompositionEnabled()) {

    #Get mainwindowhandle for powershell console process
    $hwnd = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle

    #Define margins = how much extra space to make transparent
    $margins = New-Object -TypeName 'stackoverflow.Aero+MARGINS'
    $margins.top = 50
    $margins.bottom = 0
    $margins.left = 0
    $margins.right = 0

    #Make powershell-console partly aero.
    [stackoverflow.Aero]::DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea($hwnd, $margins)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I made a few changes to your code and it kinda works! Now i have a new problem instead of the aero area of the windows form(not the console window) being transparent its white but im reading about it and there is come way to change the color to transparent, like it says somewhere here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx

Comment: Cool i made even more changes to the code and now i get the window completly transparent as if it where aero exepct the part that is off the margin is black but i got it around by setting the margins to negative values i will keep working on that